# build maven downstream projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins, m2eclipse

When Jenkins builds a project it automatically builds all downstream projects. That is, all projects that are dependent on the project beiing built. Is it possible to replicate that behaviour in Eclipse with m2eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You mean modules?

check this [link](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects):
This is the basic idea:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>exampleApp</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
     <module>dependency1</module>
     <module>dependency12</module>
     <module>mainProject</module>
   </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: No, I don't meaan Modules.

Comment: I have an application made up of projects, with various packaging types, and there is a heirarchy of dependencies. When a project is built in Jenkins, it automatically (there is an option in the project configuration) builds all the projects which are dependent on it. Of course, Jenkins only builds those projects for which it has jobs. I want to be able to do the same thing in my Eclipse workspace.

Comment: You can do this with modules(unless I'm very wrong). You create a new project in your workspace with pom packaging. Then you add your projects who have dependencies to each other in the modules section. If you then run the "root" project it will detect the dependencies and build similarly as in Jenkins